# bootstrap: modals wtih different width

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, less

I have many modals. How can I set different (fixed) width to each one of them? If is there other way than just using LESS, let me know. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override the width inline like this:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="correctModal" style="width: 400px;">
```

Or add a style in the css like this:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="correctModal">
```

CSS

```
#correctModal{
width:400px;
}
```

Comment: To keep the modal centered, you'll have to modify the margin-left too. It has to be half the width.